# Null Pointer Exception launching intent from other class

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, actionbarsherlock

I need to launch a notification when the user press the volume up button, I can´t get the keydown directly on the sherlockfragment so I created a method that is called from the sherlockfragmentactivity but I´m getting a null pointer exception on intent.putExtras(bundle)

Here is my SherlockFragmentActivity's code:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    ((MyFragment) mTabsAdapter.getItem(0)).myOnKeyDown(keyCode);            

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

Code in SherlockFragment:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotifyService.class);    
}


  public void myOnKeyDown(int key_code){

    if(key_code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
      notifyBar();                  
    }
  }
```

service intent method:

```
public void notifyBar(){                                
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong("data1", d1);        
    bundle.putLong("data2", d2);                    

    intent.putExtras(bundle); // NPE HERE           
    getActivity().startService(intent);
}
```

Log cat:

```
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.my.app.MyFragment.notifyBar(MyFragment.java:692)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.my.app.MyFragment.myOnKeyDown(MyFragment.java:393)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.my.app.MyFragmentActivity.onKeyDown(MyFragmentActivity.java:171)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1037)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2068)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:122)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 00:04:28.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you have to call `notifyBar` from other class?

Comment: @kabuto178 yes I have the notifyBar on a fragment, and I need to call it from the activityfragment

Comment: If your problem is still not solved yet, post your logcat report.

Comment: I updated the post with the logcat

Comment: How/where have you declared and initialized `intent`?

Comment: @codeMagic onActivityCreated, see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us more information?
There are two class:

- Fragment (Contains control which you want to handle after click button in FragmentActivity)
- FragmentActivity (Contains button which you want to click and notify to Fragment)

If that's what you want to, I can give you a suggestion:

You should create an interface like this:

```
interface INotifyBar {
   void notify(Object valueForTransfer); // If you want to transfer :D
}
```

In **FragmentActivity**
Right here, Please create an instance of INotifyBar

```
private INotifyBar mINotifyBar;

onKeyDown() {
    mINotifyBar.notify(keyCode); // Here is just example. :D
}
```

And In **Fragment** Where implements notify();

```
@Override
public void notify(Object obj) {
    // Handle something with or without obj. It's up to you.
}
```

I can help you more than here but, I need to know something more. :D